# How to test a controller with injection

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller

How to test a AngularJS controller with injection, for example:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('PasswordController', passwordController);
     passwordController.$inject = ['$scope'];
     //does not exist in the documentation angularjs
   function passwordController($scope) {
      $scope.password = '';
      $scope.grade = function() {
        var size = $scope.password.length;
        if (size > 8) {
          $scope.strength = 'strong';
        } else if (size > 3) {
          $scope.strength = 'medium';
        } else {
          $scope.strength = 'weak';
        }
      };
   }
```

I can not get controller in the test writing

```
describe('PasswordController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));
  var $controller;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
       $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('$scope.grade', function() {
    it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });
      // TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$controller('PasswordController');
      $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
    });
  });
});
```

With the controller model of AngularJS documentation I managed to run the test:  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

Answer (score 0):

One step in the right direction is to instantiate your `$scope` variable correctly:

```
var $rootScope, $scope, $controller;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller = _$controller_;
}));

describe('PasswordController', function() {
    var ctrl = $controller('PasswordController',{$scope: $scope});
    // Tests
});
```

Another thing - are definitely including the source of the controller in the karma.conf.js file AND are you calling that function in the controller? It doesn't look like you are...

**EDIT**

Ok so I've taken your code and incorporated it into mine. Here's a fully functional testing suite for what you have written plus some rewriting of the actual controller:

The controller:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .component('example', {
      bindings: {},
      controllerAs: "vm",
      controller: "PasswordController",
      templateUrl: 'example.html'
    });

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('PasswordController', PasswordController);

  function PasswordController(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.password = '';

    vm.grade = function() {
      var size = vm.password.length;
      if (size > 8) {
        vm.strength = 'strong';
      } else if (size > 3 && < 8) {
        vm.strength = 'medium';
      } else {
        vm.strength = 'weak';
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

And the tests (which all pass):

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    describe('PasswordController', function() {

        var $rootScope, $scope, ctrl;
        beforeEach(module('app'));

        beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller) {
            $rootScope  = _$rootScope_;
            $scope      = $rootScope.$new();

            ctrl = $controller('PasswordController',{$scope: $scope});
        }));

        describe('PasswordController', function() {
            it('should be defined', function() {
                expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
            });
            it('should initalize password to ""', function() {
                expect(ctrl.password).toBe('');
            });
            describe('grade()', function() {
                it('should set strength to "strong" if size is greater than 8', function() {
                    ctrl.password = 'password1';
                    ctrl.grade();

                    expect(ctrl.strength).toBe('strong');
                });
                it('should set strength to "medium" if size is greater than 3', function() {
                    ctrl.password = 'pass';
                    ctrl.grade();

                    expect(ctrl.strength).toBe('medium');
                });
                it('should set strength to "weak" if size is less than 3', function() {
                    ctrl.password = 'ps';
                    ctrl.grade();

                    expect(ctrl.strength).toBe('weak');
                });
            });
        });
    });
}());
```

Comment: Thanks, but tested here and has not worked. Also made ​​sure that the file is already karma.conf.js involving the controllers. 
If I implement the controller exactly as is the documentation work, but have to stop using the passwordController inject $ = [' $ scope . "] ;

Comment: @phdias No problem - accept the answer and upvote ;)

Comment: My reputation does not allow